# How to detect if another app is playing music without pausing it

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm working on a launcher for android that is meant to feel like a console. I've started working on adding audio to my app. The idea is to have the background music play unless some other audio is playing. The background music is a tune that keeps playing on loop and the user has no control over its playback, they can only set its volume.

I was able to set up a [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer) properly and get the loop going. I made it so that the launcher pauses its background music whenever onPause is called and resume the background music when onResume is called within the activity. The issue I ended up facing is knowing when to pause the background music of the launcher if another app starts playing some audio.

I've tried using [AudioManager.requestAudioFocus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#requestAudioFocus(android.media.AudioFocusRequest)), but it pauses the other app's audio in the process. And even if I use [AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK) and then abandon focus, the other app still might mute.

I've also tried using [AudioManager.isMusicActive](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#isMusicActive()), but it comes back true even if my app is playing music. To work around this I've written a little hack:

```
Handler musicHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
musicHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    boolean checkOtherApps;
    boolean waitedAFrame;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isInHome) {
            if (waitedAFrame) {
                checkOtherApps = false;
                waitedAFrame = false;
                if (!OxShellApp.getAudioManager().isMusicActive())
                    playBgMusic();
                else
                    Log.d("HomeView", "Another app is playing audio");
                musicHandler.post(this);
            } else if (checkOtherApps) {
                pauseBgMusic();
                waitedAFrame = true;
                musicHandler.post(this);
            } else {
                checkOtherApps = true;
                musicHandler.postDelayed(this, MathHelpers.calculateMillisForFps(20));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This hack does pause the background music whenever another app has audio playing. The issue is that the background music now stutters due to the constant pausing.

TL;DR
So my question is, is there a way on android to check if other apps are playing some kind of audio without stopping their playback?

Comment: You can use `MediaSessionManager` to obtain (and control) all active media sessions on the device but it requires a really dangerous notification access permission to use so it's far from ideal.

Comment: I found `MediaSessionManager` has [getActiveSessions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions(android.content.ComponentName)) that uses the [Manifest.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL) permission. I had some hope, but then read in its description that it is `Not for use by third-party applications due to privacy of media consumption`. Thanks for the suggestion, but yeah notification access permission would not be ideal.